# When is a click event raised?

Tags: .net, winforms

Looking at the MSDN documentation, it is not quite clear to me when a click event is raised. What is the order?
is it:

```
mousedown, mouseup, click?
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about WPF or Winforms or some other .NET library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. MouseDown event.
2. Click event.
3. MouseClick event.
4. MouseUp event.

This is for winforms, more information here: [Mouse Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The very definition of 'click' incorporates the mousedown and mouseup movement. You can demonstrate this by having a simply button on your form and display a Messagebox when it's clicked. The messagebox only shows after the mouse button has been released.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ASP.NET it is raised after the postback.

```
<asp:Button ID="But" runat="server" />
```

You will handle the event after the postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    But.Click += (s, ev) =>
    {
        // after the postback
        // the method Page_Load will be called again
        // re-bind the event
        // and just after it this event will be called
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking on MSDN some more I found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx

Which gives the pertinent info:

> Depressing a mouse button when the
>   cursor is over a control typically
>   raises the following series of events
>   from the control:
>
> 1. MouseDown event.
> 2. Click event.
> 3. MouseClick event.
> 4. MouseUp event.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to its name, a `Click` event may not be associated with mouse activity at all.

For example, if you set the [ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys.aspx) property, then the `Click` event for that menu item will fire whenever the shortcut key (combination) is pressed.

Another example is "clicking" a button by hitting enter.